# Buissness validation logic

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, validation

is there any nice solution to validate domains after changing?

For example:
In our buisiness case we got **Users** as domain object. 
The UserGlobal has a expiration timeframe (**activeFrom** and **activeTo**). When the admin is changing this timeframe it needs to check serval other domains like BankDataExpiration timeframes, Contract timeframes etc.... Today we use a big ugly block with all checks in one class.

some pseudo code:

```
public class UsersService {
    public void onUserChange(Users users) {

        checkContracts();
        checkBankdata();
        // much other validation checks....
    }
}
```

After the whole ugly check thing, it is possible that data should change automatically. For example Some of the timeframes could be cut.

But all of this is hurts the "Single Responsibility Principle" and its unreadable and unmaintainable. Is there a nice and clever solution out there, I didn't find yet?

We thought already about a interface for checking and validation that will be autowired via spring beans. But we got trouble with hibernates session handling. We changed some reletad data in the session a error apeard, the user changed the data and tries to revalidate it. The validation passes and the previously changed objects will be comitted too.

I hope this question is not to general :S

Comment: You could create a `Validation` interface and create several implementations, iterate over them in  your `onUserChange` method. This would allow to split things (maybe reuse some validations?) and probably be more testable.

Comment: It is a very opinionated question - you are already voicing several yourself, for example that the above is ugly. I find it quite readable and thus not ugly - it is only not very reusable. I can say "move the checks to a singular reusable checkUser() method in a proper business logic class" and everyone else can completely disagree with me; that's because only in my opinion that is a good idea, I am not stating hard facts. Nor can I state hard facts the way that the question is asked.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own custom validators. Follow the below steps:

1. declare your own annotation using '@Constraint'

   `@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
   @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)

   @Constraint(validatedBy=BankDataExpirationValidator.class)
   public @interface BankDataExpiration {`
2. Implement the validation logic by implementing `ConstraintValidator` interface e.g. `BankDataExpirationValidator`
3. Then annotate the `Users` class with the above created annotation, `@BankDataExpiration`

You can create different kinds of validators this way and map it to your domain objects.